# How to project filtered 2nd level child objects in Linq to Entities?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have this `Parent -> Child -> Child` relationsship. (`Store -> Message -> MessageText`).

In the projected result, I want to have all related `Messages` from the `Store`, but only a filtered sub set of the `MessageTexts` (for a specific language).
So I was playing with something like:

```
  var result = from s in context.Stores 
  join m in context.Messages on s.Id equals m.MessageId
  join mt in context.MessageTexts on m.MessageId equals mt.MessageId  into mts
  from filtered in mts.Where (mt => mt.LanguageId == 1)

  select new
    {
      StoreName = s.Name,
      Messages = s.Messages,
    };
```

So the `filtered` set is what I want to appear in the `result.Messages.MessageTexts` navigation property.
How can I do that in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have navigation properties available. That would make

```
from s in context.Stores
select new {
               StoreName = s.Name,
               Messages = from m in s.Messages
                          from mt in m.MessageTexts
                          where mt.LanguageId == 1
                          select mt
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple queries:

```
var stores = context.Stores.Include("Messages").ToList();
var messageIds = stores.Messages.Select(m => m.MessageId).ToList();
var messageTexts = context.Messagetexts.Where(m => messageIds.Contains(m.MessageId) && m.LanguageId == 1);
```

With one query and just one level deep hierarchy you can do it like this:

```
var query = from s in context.Stores
             Select Stores = s
                    Messages = from m in context.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageId.Equals(s.Id) && someOtherFilter)

var result = from s in query.Stores.ToList();
```

so i suspect you can filter deeper nested childs like this:

```
var query = from s in context.Stores
            Select Stores = s
                   Messages = from m1 in context.Messages
                              Select Messages = m1
                                     MessageTexts = from context.MessageTexts.Where(m => m.MessageId.Equals(m1.MessageId) && m.LanguageId == 1);

var result = from s in query.Stores.ToList();
```

I have no VS here, will test it in some hours.

Comment: Sorry, neither of your 3 examples are in proper Linq syntax and not compilable.